# Is the largest eigenvalue of $A$ is greater than that of $B$?

Tags: matrices, graph-theory

Let $A_1$ and $A_2$ be adjacency matrices of two nonsingular bipartite graphs of order $m$ and $n$.

Let $C_1=\begin{pmatrix}
 0 & 0 &0 & \cdots 0\\
 \vdots&\vdots&\vdots&\vdots \\
 0 & 0 &0 & \cdots 0\\
1 & 1 &0 & \cdots 0\\
1 & 1 &0 & \cdots 0\\
0 & 0 &0 & \cdots 0\\
\end{pmatrix}$ and $C_2=\begin{pmatrix}
 0 & 0 &0 & \cdots 0\\
 \vdots&\vdots&\vdots&\vdots \\
 0 & 0 &0 & \cdots 0\\
1 & 1 &0 & \cdots 0\\
\end{pmatrix}$ be two $m\times n$ matrices.

Define $A=\begin{pmatrix} 
A_1 & C_1\\
C_1^T & A_2
\end{pmatrix} \text{  and } B=\begin{pmatrix}
A_1 & C_2\\
C_2^T & A_2
\end{pmatrix}$.

Is it true that the largest eigenvalue of $A$ is greater than that of $B$? Any hint to prove this?

Comment: These matrices seem very arbitrary to me... do you have reasons to believe this is true?